# How to parameterize the Step Name in AWS EMR?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-emr

I have tried to concat something with the Name value-

```
step = {"Name": "what_you_do-" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H:%M"),
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 's3n://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
            'Args': 'sd'
        }
```

But it gives Parameter Validation Error-

```
    "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Steps[0].HadoopJarStep.Args, value: sd, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
```

When I try the below approach, then also it throws Parameter Validation error-

```
{"Name.$": "$.variable",
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 's3n://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
            'Args': 'sd'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Args must be an array sample below

```
'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 's3n://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
            'Args': ['sd']
        }
```

Comment: Actually the argument part is okay for me. Wanted to know if there is a way to parameterize the "Name".